# Concatenate 2 Columns into new Column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I need help with concatenating 2 Columns into a new column.

I have the following dataset

[image]

The ideal result would look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heavily commented to help with understanding :)

To make it work, just change the `WB` and `WS` variables.

```
Sub concatCells()
    ' declare variable types - immutable                              do not modify
    Dim WB As Workbook                                                '  workbook             - full name of the file containing data.
    Dim WS As Worksheet                                               '  worksheet            - worksheet within  workbook containing data.
    Dim i As Long                                                     ' loop variables        - used to iterate through loops. not user defined.
    Dim lRow As Long                                                  ' last row              - last row with data found in the  column. not constant / user defined.

    ' variables - mutable                                             ok to modify
    Set WB = Workbooks("SO.xlsm")                                     ' set the name of the  workbook here
    Set WS = WB.Worksheets("63627727")                                ' set the name of the  worksheet here
    
    ' code - immutable                                                do not modify
    lRow = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                 ' find the last row in Col of the WS object
    
    For i = 1 To lRow                                                 ' creates a For loop and declares i as each iteration (i = 1 then i = 2, etc)
        WS.Range("B" & i) = WS.Range("A" & i) & WS.Range("C" & i)    ' concats cells A and C into B
        
        ' uncomment below to concat data into column A and clear column C
        ' WS.Range("A" & i) = WS.Range("A" & i) & WS.Range("C" & i)   ' concats cells A and C into A
        ' WS.Range("C" & i).Clear                                     ' clears contents of C
        
    Next                                                              ' iterate to next cell within defined range for primary loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late reply. Yes, both of the lines work. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Very basic thing. Simply use below formula

```
=A1 & C1
```

[image]

Comment: OP has VBA tagged.

Comment: But why need `VBA` for this simple issue? Should encourage to use excel formula only.

Comment: I absolutely don't disagree lol. Overkill if it's simple. OP might have something else going on.

Comment: This is just a sample dataset I created. I have a larger dataset which I have to use the same function. Appreciate your reply !